# Fetch Token from Kafka Message and Inject it to all feign calls

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, jwt, openfeign

I have a scenario. My Microservice A is sending Kafka Message to ServiceB. Service B is consuming that message and after processing it is Sending update request to Service C.

I am sending Oauth token from Service A to Service B in kafka message field. How can I inject that token to All feign calls in Service B.

Comment: I think it is a very bad idea to include Oauth tokens in kafka, why do you need to include that?